# Alamofire reports downloadProgress incorrectly when downloading multiple URLs in same request

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift5, alamofire-request

```
func test(){
        
        let urls = ["https://www.sample-videos.com/zip/30mb.zip", "https://www.sample-videos.com/zip/30mb.zip", "https://www.sample-videos.com/zip/30mb.zip"].compactMap { URL(string: $0) }
        
        for i in urls{
            let destination: DownloadRequest.Destination = { _, _ in
                var documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
                documentsURL.appendPathComponent("duck.zip")
                return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile])
            }
            AF.download(i, to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { progess in
                print(progess.fractionCompleted * 100)
            }).responseData { response in
                print(response)
            }
        }
    }
```

printed values -

0.6780020344008234
0.9387720476319094
0.9909260502781266
1.0430800529243438
0.7301560370470407
1.0952340555705609
1.1473880582167781
0.7823100396932579
0.834464042339475
1.1995420608629954
0.8866180449856922
1.2516960635092125
1.3038500661554298
1.3560040688016468
1.408158071447864
1.5124660767402984
1.5646200793865157
1.6167740820327328
0.9387720476319094
0.9909260502781266
1.0430800529243438
1.0952340555705609
1.1473880582167781
1.1995420608629954
1.2516960635092125
0.7301560370470407
0.7823100396932579
0.834464042339475
1.66892808467895
1.8253900926176014
1.8775440952638187
0.8866180449856922
1.3038500661554298
1.3560040688016468
0.9909260502781266
1.408158071447864
1.4603120740940814
1.9818521005562533
1.5646200793865157
1.0430800529243438
2.0340061032024703
1.6167740820327328
2.0861601058486876
1.66892808467895
2.1383141084949044
2.1904681111411217
1.7732360899713844
1.0952340555705609
1.8775440952638187
1.1473880582167781
1.9296980979100358
2.242622113787339
2.346930119079773
1.1995420608629954
2.0340061032024703
1.2516960635092125
2.503392127018425

Comment: How do you confirm that it's incorrect? There are there files downloading concurrently.

Comment: @MBT when adding this to progressView it's mutating the level, which means automatically increasing and decreasing. Do you know any solution for it?

Comment: Did you add these to a single progressView? If yes, then you have to use 3 different progressView.

Comment: @MBT yes implemented to a single progressView, No I want to add a single progressView

Comment: Then the current behaviour is expected. Cause 3 files are downloaded at the same time and their download progress aren't same. That's why in progress block you get inconsistent progress.

Comment: @MBT it's not downloading at the same time, it's looping

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244679/discussion-between-achinthaishane-and-mbt).